# Magento admin CMS pages content in wrong tab

Tags: magento, content-management-system

I've got a Magento site however when I login into the admin area to create a new CMS page the content box is appearing in the Page Information tab and not the Content tab. This is causing the validation to fail when I add the content.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please tag the version of Magento you are using.  Example: `Magento 1.6.1`

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling any third party extensions/customizations you may of installed.

It could also be caused by corrupted database entries.

Try reinstalling Magento to a new database and seeing if the issue persists.

If it's fixed, then it's a problem with your data.  If it isn't, then it must be a extension or customization causing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System>Configuration>Advanced** and you will see a brand of extension you recently installed. Set it to disabled and hit **Save Config**. **Flush Cache**, log out and log back in to admin and it should be corrected. If it is, contact the extension creator and report the bug as it shouldnt do that.The only realy way for that to happen is for something to overrule its placement which would be a 3rd party extension.

The other possibility is that you moved some folders in adminhtml by accident. If thats the case, try uploading an original copy of adminhtml.